# Lifecycle of android with cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am making a hybrid app with Apache Cordova.

According to [this Cordova document](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#testing-the-activity-lifecycle).

> 1. The user is interacting with your app and needs to take a picture
> 2. The camera plugin launches the native camera activity
> 3. The OS destroys the Cordova activity (pause event is fired)
> 4. The user takes a photo
> 5. The camera activity finishes
> 6. The OS recreates the Cordova activity (deviceready and resume events are fired)
>      The user is confused as to why they are suddenly back at your app's login screen

When device has low memory, the above scenarios could occur.

So, I needed a way which i can test the scenarios.

I tried to use "Don't keep activities" option like below.

> Android provides a developer setting for testing Activity destruction on low > memory. Enable the "Don't keep activities" setting in the Developer Options menu on your device or emulator to simulate low memory scenarios. You should always do some amount of testing with this setting enabled to make sure that your application is properly maintaining state.

I turned on camera activity by using plugin and took a photo.
When i closed camera, my app went to background automatically.
And then i switched to my app. my app was recreated correctly.

But, i could not receive Resume Event. (it is my main problem)

In the above document, both of deviceready and resume events should be fired. But, it was not. (only deviceready was fired)

Did i miss something? or If i make low memory scenario correctly on my device, Will both events occur?

Additionally, Is there any way to make low memory scenario for testing in Android with Cordova?

Please, somebody help me.

Comment: if you start don't keep activity from developer option. your activity never be in background and every time it recreate your activity. so turn of that option. it is not helpful to test low memory case

Comment: in native also when you call camera from your activity it will goes in on pause state and when it returns it calls onresume , onActivityresult for camera picture result

Comment: @Jack Thank you, Jack. You save me!
Eventually, i could test low memory scenario with some app which can fill ram gradually.

Comment: Contrary to J.D.'s comment, the "don't keep activities" option _is_ helpful to test the low memory case. It gives your activity the chance to save its state, and provides it when the activity gets started up again.